# How can I accessing a react app in Virtualbox

Tags: reactjs, networking, virtualbox

Trying to connect to a react app that is running inside a Virtualbox wit Ubuntu 18.04.

Did the network config on virtualbox by adding a second network configured via NAT and added all my forwarded ports.

[image: First network, Bridged]
[image: Second network, NAT]

Ports forwarded:
[image: Ports forwarded]

Server ports listening:
[image: Server ports listening]

Result when trying to connect to port:
[image: Web browser result]

My problem is that all the other ports that I am forwarding work perfectly except for 3000 or 3001, which are both react apps.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify **Host IP** and **Guest IP** in port forwarding.

To define **Guest IP** you need to call `ifconfig` command via console and find **inet addr**. In my case it equals to *10.0.2.15*.

Your **Host IP** is 192.168.0.6 based on the screenshot above.